# Is there an R function for finding the specific range of correlations?

Tags: r, plot, correlation, r-corrplot

Does anyone know if there's a function for showing me only the specific range of correlations in a plot?

I used the function below for making a huge correlation plot.

```
paasall <- read.csv("49PAAS.csv",header=TRUE)
paasall

cols <- character(nrow(paasall))
cols[] <- "black"
myCol <- rep(colors()[1:49],each=2)      
pdf("P_PASS49Corr.pdf", width=49, height=49)
pairs(paasall, panel=panel.smooth)  
dev.off()
```

As you can see below, I have 49 elements and the graph is showing me how correlate each other. However, I only want to divide them into three different categories: (1) highly correlated (more than 80% of r-squared value), (2) moderately correlated (more than 70% of r-squared value), and (3) low or no correlated (less than 60% of r-squared value).

[image]

I also attached a .csv file that I used (in an image file, I don't know how to attach an original file to this post) below just in case you need it for helping me out. Please help me with this. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Instead of a bunch of plots, look at the correlation matrix, `cor(paasall)`

Comment: Please post your data

Comment: How am I going to post my data? This website doesn't allow me to post .csv file.